# Обновление компилятора gcc с версии 4.4.3 до 4.6.1 под Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: gcc, ubuntu

Как мне обновить мой gcc компилятор под ubuntu 10.04 LTS
В данный момент у меня:

```
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)
```

Я скачал самую последнюю версию компилятора gcc 4.6.1 
файл: gcc-4.6.1.tar.bz2

Как мне безболезненно обновить его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В идеале было бы неплохо собрать deb пакет и установить его, но это непростой способ.
Если я не ошибаюсь, можно собрать и установить обычным способом:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Несколько версий gcc могут безболезнено соседствовать на одной машине. 
После указанной выше процедуры компилятор будет находится по пути
/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.6
Для удаления надо выполнить

```
make uninstall
```

в директории где собирался gcc.

Answer (score 2):

[gcc_4.6.1-2ubuntu5_i386.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/gcc/download)

Comment: а проблемы никакие не возникнут?

Comment: Разрешите неудовлетворённые зависимости при установке - не возникнут)

Comment: Я не знаю как это делать, ладно, спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте из бинарных пакетов с [LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/~linaro-maintainers/+archive/toolchain)

Comment: добавить в репозиторий Ubuntu это надо?

Comment: Да.